# Setting the extent in cartodb to the sublayer bounds

Tags: carto, extents, carto-js

How do you set the extent of a sublayer to fit all of the points?

I've been trying to use [this bounds function](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-3-25), but it doesn't work:

```
sql.getBounds('select * from table').done(function(bounds) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there any message in the command console? What does the rest of your code look like? Are you using createLayer or createVis?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew says, your approach should be working.

For example:

```
   var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'iriberri' });
   sql.getBounds("SELECT * FROM world_borders_9").done(function(bounds) {
   map.fitBounds(bounds)
```

You can see this code live working [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/ce3a5a491939957f76c9).